# maximum value of $\sum (a-b)^2$

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, symmetric-polynomials

> If $a^2+b^2+c^2=5$ and $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R},$ find the maximum
>
> value of $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2$.

My Try: $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2=2(a^2+b^2+c^2)-2(ab+bc+ac)$

$$=10-2(ab+bc+ac)$$

Now this implies $ab+bc+ac\le 5$. So

$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 = 10-2(ab+bc+ac) \geq 20.$$

Could some help me to find max of $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2$? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to use Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: What is $\sum(a-b)^2$ meant to be? Without further explanation this is nonsense. You should also edit your exercise. It is not clear what you are supposed to do.

Comment: @amsmath It's pretty clear from the context what this means.

Comment: I think OP meant $\sum (a-b)^2 = (a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2$

Comment: @Servaes Nope, it isn't.

Comment: @Servaes It wasn't to me. qed

Comment: DXT, your implication that the thing is $\ge 20$ is not correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2=3(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(a+b+c)^2\leq15.$$
The equality occurs for $a+b+c=0,$ which says that we got a maximal value.

Comment: whats wrong with cauchy Inequality. $(a^2+b^2+c^2)(b^2+c^2+a^2)\geq (ab+bc+ca)^2$ means $-5 \leq (ab+bc+ca)\leq 5$

Comment: @DXT It's not wrong. It just does not help. $ab+ac+bc\leq5$ gives $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2\geq0,$ which is trivial without using $ab+ac+bc\leq5$. But $ab+ac+bc\geq-5$ gives $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2\leq20,$ which does not give a maximal value because the equality does not occur.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more visual approach; for a point $(a,b,c)\in\Bbb{R}^3$ the condition that
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=5,$$
is equivalent to being on the sphere of radius $\sqrt{5}$ centered at the origin, and
$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2=||(a,b,c)-(b,c,a)||^2,$$
where the point $(b,c,a)\in\Bbb{R}^3$ is obtained from $(a,b,c)$ by a rotation of one third of a full turn around the line spanned by $(1,1,1)$. Then clearly the distance is maximal precisely when $(a,b,c)$ is on the equator w.r.t. the axis of rotation, and as the following picture shows;
[image]
by elementary geometry the distance between $(a,b,c)$ and $(b,c,a)$ is $\sqrt{3}$ times the radius, which is $\sqrt{5}$. Hence the desired maximum is $(\sqrt{3}\times\sqrt{5})^2=15$.